# Powershell: How to obtain the complete list of distribution groups

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I am completely new to powershell, I have never touched this scripting language before. However, I have some backgrounds in perl and bash scripting. I am trying to implement a small script that will obtain the list of DG in Exchange server, filters the results to get only the groups that have a certain string, corresponding to the current year.

Example: check the year, in this case 2011.
Filter Name Contains 'P11' 
Return only the last DG name and parse the first 7 characters.

How could I do this using powershell from an exchange server? Here is what I got:

```
add-pssnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010

# Retrieve all DGs
$temp = Get-DistributionGroup -ResultSize Unlimited | 

foreach($group in $temp) 
{ 
write-output "GroupName:$group " 
Write-output "GroupMembers:" 
Get-DistributionGroupMember $group |ft displayname,alias,primarysmtpaddress 
write-output ‘ ‘ 

}
```

this results in the following error:

> Unexpected token 'in' in expression or statement. At
>   C:\Users\jfb\Desktop\NewGroupProject.ps1:7 char:18
>   + foreach($group in <<<<  $temp)
>       + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (in:String) [],
>   ParseException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (not tested). Create a date object,using Get-Date, and format the date to include the last two digits of the year enclosed in asterisks. This would be the wildcard for the Get-DistributionGroup cmdlet. Select the last DG object and expand its name.

```
$name = Get-Date -Format *Pyy*
$group = Get-DistributionGroup $name | Select-Object -Last 1 -ExpandProperty Name

if($group)
{
    $group.Substring(0,7)
}
```

Comment: thank you! Please view my other question if you can also help with that, it would be great!

Answer (score 2):

Remove the trailing `|` in the line `$temp = Get-DistributionGroup -ResultSize Unlimited |` and it should work fine.

What is happening is that since you had the `|` it is treating the `foreach` as a `foreach-object`